# Object reference not set to an instance of object error when returning list

Tags: c#

This is my class

```
[DataContract]
    public class Edit_BuildTeam
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int TEAMID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string PROJECTMNAME { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<MultiEMPID> EMPLOYEEID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string TEAMCREATIONON { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string TEAMCREATEDBY { get; set; }
         [DataMember]
        public int STATUS { get; set; }

    }
```

This the class which i use in Edit_BuildTeam class as a List:

```
[DataContract]
public class MultiEMPID
{
        [DataMember]
        public int _EMPLOYEEID { get; set; }
          [DataMember]
        public string EMPNAME { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my svc.cs logic function

```
Edit_BuildTeam ESM = new Edit_BuildTeam();

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        ESM.PROJECTMNAME = dt.Rows[i]["PROJECTMNAME"].ToString();
        ESM.TEAMCREATIONON = dt.Rows[i]["CREATEDON"].ToString();
        ESM.TEAMCREATEDBY = dt.Rows[i]["TEAMCREATEDBY"].ToString();
        ESM.STATUS = int.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["STATUS"].ToString());
    }

    MultiEMPID MEP = new MultiEMPID() ;
    MEP._EMPLOYEEID = (Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i].  
         ["EMPLOYEEID"].ToString()));
    MEP.EMPNAME = dt.Rows[i]["EMPLOYEENAME"].ToString();
    ESM.EMPLOYEEID.Add(MEP );
}

return ESM;
```

Employeeid and employee name values come from database. When I am debugging my code, it works perfectly.

When I'm adding to the list i.e. `ESM.EMPLOYEEID.Add(MEP );`, there's an error. Where is the mistake?

Comment: I have marked your question as a duplicate. Please check the linked question for very thorough answers to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate the list. `EMPLOYEEID = New List<MultiEMPID>()`
I would create a public void New() method in your class and instatiate it there. That way whenever an instance of your class is created, the list will also be instantiated.

Comment: In C#, a constructor is is a method with no return type and the same name as the class - not a `New` method.